# How to keep a PWA / webapp running on android when picking files

Tags: android, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA that run well on mobile, at some point the user take a picture from the camera or select a file from the phone and at this point when the file selection is done, the app reload from start, saying "Impossible to end operation... not enough memory."

I understand that my app is kicked off because memory is needed. 
So my questions are : 
- maybe is it possible anyway to keep it alive as such
- if not then how can I retrieve the data that the file picker send usually to the input if the app starts from zero
- maybe using a trick with the service worker ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the HTML5 file API to read data on the file to be uploaded. Also avoid reading the entire file into memory. What you can do is upload small parts of the file in chunks, asynchronously, and stitch them back together again on the server side. Try using Plupload or a similar JS plugin that supports HTML5 file chunking.

Lastly, you might want to avoid showing a preview of the photo prior to uploading it, as this too can be taxing on memory.

Comment: Actually, I may have not made myself clear, when my app remains opened I then use the File API (FileReader) to process my files as I wish. But the problem is that during the time I spend selecting the files (using any android file explorer or camera) my web app close. When My selection is done it then re-launch the app, but then all state is lost and I don't know even if it is possible to retrieve those file selected by android that should populate my input tag.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to put the state into IDB or localStorage.  Recommend a library called localForage for this (it selects the most advanced form of local storage that the browser can handle, and uses the syntax of the localStorage API). It is promise-based so you'll need to think asynchronously. This might allow you to recover some of that precious memory that could be causing the app to relaunch.  

Anyway, in a PWA it's good practice to store state in local storage for just this type of scenario, and when users have to minimize the app or temporarily flip over to another app.

Comment: Another thing that occurred to me.  If your app is a single page application, this architecture might be a memory hog.  SPAs and their related frameworks take up a lot of memory real estate.  If you're not too deep into your project, maybe consider an ajax-enabled Multi Page App.  Here's a video by a Google engineer who used a Multi Page App approach in his PWA:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/beyond-spa